# rails 3 + active record: how do I do something like stores = Store.User_find_all_by_owner_name("Ted")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I'm having trouble understanding how to do a simple query that combines all the Stores that are owned by all the Users who are named "Ted"

my class User `has_many :stores`
and user.owner_name is the name of the store owner

my class Store `belongs_to :user`

`users = User.find_all_by_owner_name("Ted")` pulls all my users named Ted

But how do I then get all the stores that are owned by that set of users (named Ted)?

I need to get that list as a single record set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it

```
Store.joins(:user).where('users.owner_name = ?', 'Ted')
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to only include the fields from Store... if I wanted stores.name and users.email, is there a way to have the recordset contain those fields from each table?

Comment: never mind. dumb question! in my virew I just do store.user.email. duh! Thanks very much!